# PHP / AJAX toolkit to make a "live graph" (eg for tracing stock prices)

Tags: php, ajax, graph, stocks

how do i (after getting the right stock prices from a source) show it on a "live graph". i'm looking for a php/ajax toolkit that allows me to create that graph live?

is that the right thing to use or a flash based solution is better?

are there 3rdparty sites that offer to create live graphs given input data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Highcharts](http://highcharts.com/) is probably what you need.

I recently started a new project to simplify the construction of a graph when using php:

http://aloiroberto.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/highcharts-php-library/

Also, [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/) or [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/) are concrete possibilities (the latter will require Flash).

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at **[JPGRAPH](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/)**. It is a wonderful library for creating wide variety of graphs.
As far as ajax is concerned this library outputs the graph as a picture file, so you can easily send the required parameters using ajax and build the graph dynamically using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

PHPlot also is a free library: http://phplot.sourceforge.net, but compared to JPGraph it's  rather limited. It also delivers a picture so you could grab that via AJAX and display it.

Answer (score 0):

[Birdeye](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/) has some incredibly powerful graphing tools.  Check out the [Birdeye Explorer](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/branches/ng/examples/demo/BirdEyeExplorer.html) to get a sense of what you can do with it.